# Removing leaflet layers and L.marker method

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I was wondering if anyone knows how or if you can actually remove a layer of points after adding them using this convention:

```
var pointsLayer, someFeatures = [{
            //Hard coded for now
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "name": "Company A",
                "show_on_map": true,
                "icon": 'img/violations.png'
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [43.22519, -107.69348]
            }
        }, {
            "type": "Feature",
           .
           .
           .
   }];
for(w=0; w < someFeatures.length; w++){
                pointsLayer = L.marker(someFeatures[w].geometry.coordinates, {icon: violations})   
                    .bindPopup("Company: "+someFeatures[w].properties.name);
                    //add map points 
                    map.addLayer(pointsLayer);
            }
```

The typical removeLayer(pointsLayer); within a similar for loop does not work for me. But, that does not mean that there isn't a way to loop through. I am just not sure exactly how. I am trying to add points, which is working, and then remove them on an event (not working). Any ideas?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Instead of adding all markers directly on the map, you can add the markers on a separate layer (i.e. `var markers = new L.FeatureGroup();`) and then add that layer on the map (`map.addLayer(markers);`) outside the loop.

For example,

http://jsfiddle.net/9BXL7/

**html**

```
<button>remove all markers</button>
<div id="map"></div>
```

**css**

```
html, body, #map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

**js**

```
var cloudmade = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/{key}/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; 2011 OpenStreetMap contributors, Imagery &copy; 2011 CloudMade',
    key: 'BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707'
});

var map = L.map('map')
    .setView([50.5, 30.51], 15)
    .addLayer(cloudmade);

var markers = new L.FeatureGroup();

function getRandomLatLng(map) {
    var bounds = map.getBounds(),
        southWest = bounds.getSouthWest(),
        northEast = bounds.getNorthEast(),
        lngSpan = northEast.lng - southWest.lng,
        latSpan = northEast.lat - southWest.lat;

    return new L.LatLng(
    southWest.lat + latSpan * Math.random(),
    southWest.lng + lngSpan * Math.random());
}

function populate() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var marker = L.marker(getRandomLatLng(map));
        marker.bindPopup("<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec odio. Quisque volutpat mattis eros. Nullam malesuada erat ut turpis. Suspendisse urna nibh, viverra non, semper suscipit, posuere a, pede.</p><p>Donec nec justo eget felis facilisis fermentum. Aliquam porttitor mauris sit amet orci. Aenean dignissim pellentesque.</p>", {
            showOnMouseOver: true
        });
        markers.addLayer(marker);
    }
    return false;
}

map.addLayer(markers);

populate();
function removeAllMarkers(){
    map.removeLayer(markers);
}
document.querySelector('button').onclick=function(){removeAllMarkers()};
```

Should you need to DELETE or clear the markers layer to swap out the points in the future use:

```
markers.clearLayers();
```

Answer (score 12):

Use `map.removeLayer()`:

```
var circle = L.circle([lat, lng], 1000).addTo(map);
map.removeLayer(circle);
```

Comment: Code only answers can generally benefit from some explanation to go with the code. Late answers are improved by explaining how they differ from existing answers.

Comment: I wouldn't have classified this as "code only" because of the words "Use map.removeLayer:

The way in which it differs that I think is important, is that there is less information to digest. I was adding it for people who were scanning rather than really reading things in detail... so adding _more information_ to something I was intentionally trying leave sparse would have been odd.

Answer (score 0):

You can go over all layers directly in object 'map'.

```
for ( key in map['_layers'] ){
    if(typeof map['_layers'][key]['feature'] !== 'undefined') {
        var l = map['_layers'][key];
        if( l['feature']['properties']['name'] === 'Company A' ) l.removeFrom(map);}}
```