# How to use ajax on PruneCluster

Tags: javascript, ajax, leaflet

I use ajax to update location of markers every 10seconds with [PruneCluster](https://github.com/SINTEF-9012/PruneCluster)

```
       (function update() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://wanderdrone.appspot.com/',
            dataType: 'json',  //The data type expected of the server response.
            success: function (data) {

                var leafletView = new PruneClusterForLeaflet();
                leafletView.BuildLeafletClusterIcon = function (cluster) {
                    var e = new L.Icon.MarkerCluster();
                    e.stats = cluster.stats;
                    e.population = cluster.population;
                    cluster.ENABLE_MARKERS_LIST = true
                    return e;
                };

                var markers = [];
                var myServerData = data;  //server response
                console.log(data);
                map.setView(new L.LatLng((myServerData.geometry.coordinates[1]), (myServerData.geometry.coordinates[0])), 12)
                var marker = new PruneCluster.Marker((myServerData.geometry.coordinates[1]), (myServerData.geometry.coordinates[0]));
                markers.push(marker);
                leafletView.RegisterMarker(marker);
                leafletView.ProcessView();
                map.addLayer(leafletView)

            }

        })
            .then(function () {           // on completion, restart
                setTimeout(update, 10000);  // function refers to itself
            });
    })();
```

I have new marker's location update but it doesn't seem to delete the previous's marker's layer. The new markers keep drawing on top of the old one and they are still there. 
I keep getting the new markers and cluster drawing ontop of the old one. I am wondering how can I delete the previous marker's later and using the new one.

Comment: Try this link: `https://stackoverflow.com/a/24331645/5737771`

Comment: Here is remove all markers example: http://jsfiddle.net/9BXL7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I've made a few updates to your code.*

I see you're creating a new array on each ajax request and creating a new marker as well. What is happening here is you're not neccesarily updating the cluster marker, you're simply creating new instances of the marker which would explain why the new marker gets plotted over the previous one.

The best approach which is working for me is to first initialize your array as a global variable, then before you create a marker from your ajax request, check if there's already an existing instance of that marker in the array (this is achieved by assigning an id to the marker using the **marker.data** object). If it doesn't exist, you create it, if it does, you update it.

```js
const map = L.map("map", {
  attributionControl: false,
  zoomControl: false
}).setView(new L.LatLng(59.911111, 10.752778), 4);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  detectRetina: true,
  maxNativeZoom: 17
}).addTo(map);

let markers = [];
const leafletView = new PruneClusterForLeaflet();

leafletView.BuildLeafletClusterIcon = function(cluster) {
  var e = new L.Icon.MarkerCluster();
  e.stats = cluster.stats;
  e.population = cluster.population;
  cluster.ENABLE_MARKERS_LIST = true
  return e;
};

const update = () => {
  $.ajax({
      url: 'https://wanderdrone.appspot.com/',
      dataType: 'json', //The data type expected of the server response.
      success: function(data) {

        const myServerData = data; //server response
        console.log(data);
        map.setView(new L.LatLng((myServerData.geometry.coordinates[1]), (myServerData.geometry.coordinates[0])), 12)

        /** Check if Marker Already Exists On Map */
        const markerAlreadyExists = checkIfMarkerExists(myServerData.id); //assuming your responses have ids. Else u can just generate random uuids.

        switch (markerAlreadyExists) {
          case true:
            const existingMarker = getExistingMaker(myServerData.id);
            existingMarker.position.lat = myServerData.geometry.coordinates[1];
            existingMarker.position.lng = myServerData.geometry.coordinates[0];
            leafletView.ProcessView();
            break;
          case false:
            const marker = new PruneCluster.Marker((myServerData.geometry.coordinates[1]), (myServerData.geometry.coordinates[0]));
            markers.push(marker);
            leafletView.RegisterMarker(marker);
            leafletView.ProcessView();
            break;
        }

      }

    })
    .then(function() { // on completion, restart
      setTimeout(update, 10000); // function refers to itself
    });
}
update(); //INVOKE UPDATE FUNCTION

map.addLayer(leafletView);


/**
 * FUNCTION TO CHECK IF A MARKER EXISTS IN MARKER ARRAY
 * ----------------------------------------------------
 * @param {String} id
 */
const checkIfMarkerExists = id => {
  let exists = false;
  for (const existingMarker of markers) {
    if (existingMarker.data.id === id) {
      exists = true;
    }
  }
  return exists;
};


/**
 * FUNCTION TO RETRIEVE AN EXISTING MARKER FROM MARKER ARRAY
 * ---------------------------------------------------------
 * @param {String} id
 */
const getExistingMaker = id => {
  let markerObject = new Object();
  for (const existingMarker of markers) {
    if (existingMarker.data.id === id) {
      markerObject = existingMarker;
    }
  }
  return markerObject;
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

div#size,
a#delete {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
  top: 1em;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 0.4em;
  border-radius: 4px;
  z-index: 500;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>PruneCluster - AjAX</title>

  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.0.0-beta.2.rc.2/leaflet.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.0.0-beta.2.rc.2/leaflet.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prunecluster/2.1.0/PruneCluster.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

[You can clone and take a look at this simple spring-boot project on my github](https://github.com/lkgamor/map-application)

Comment: My sample project however uses websocket to consume data from a backend service via centrifuge.js